# Are Certain Magical Item Not Disenchantable Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a magic staff that has an enchant that summons a familiar for 60 seconds wherever the caster is pointing but when I go to the arcane enchanter table, it does not show for for disenchanting.  Are there certain things you can disenchant or do I need to be certain level in enchanting to disenchant these items?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may neither enchant nor disenchant staves.

Additionally, you may not disenchant unless the item has an enchamtment you don't already know.

Additionally, there are some quest rewards you may not disenchant (for example: Ghost Sword).

And finally, there are some items (such as the Amulet of [Insert Aedra here]) that you simply can't disenchant.

Comment: additionally there are apparel items such as some Dark Brotherhood items that cannot be disenchanted. I havent confirmed this totally but it seems to me that if there isnt an 'of [effect]' then it can't be disenchanted.